# VBA Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel, cycle

I'm just getting familiar with VBA and my code

```
xxLastrow = xLastRow+1
For x = 11 To xLastRow
For y = 12 To xxLastrow
If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 2).Value = Cells(y, 2).Value Then
For z = 4 To xLastColumn
If ActiveSheet.Cells(y, z).Value <> "" Then  '(possible If Not IsEmpty(Cells(y, z).Value))
ActiveSheet.Cells(y, z).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells(x, z).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next z
End If
Next y
Next x
```

makes Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error when the line "If ActiveSheet.Cells(y, z).Value <> ""  Then" goes. All variables are integer (including lastrow/column). What's the problem here?
I promise sea of cats for man who will try to help :)

Comment: What is `xLastColumn` and where have you defined it?

Comment: Also I feel that the error is not on that line but on `Cells(y, 2).Value` or `ActiveSheet.Cells(y, z).Select` or `ActiveSheet.Cells(x, z).Select`

Comment: xLastcolumn is numer of columns filled in previous steps. It was taken from another cycle (the same with xLastColumn). There is no error on Cells value or select, why should it be?

Comment: ok. Did you see my last comment?

Comment: @SiddharthRout  yep, sorry, slow internet :) so why there should be an error on cells selection and so on? arguments are numbers, I don't see any rules broken. I'd rather prefer to operate with range, but it's hard with cycle running - i don't want to insert function

Comment: As is the code should work, Are you sure that line is causing the error? Try to make the variable of type Long instead of Integer You might be over flowing the variables.

Comment: Try using normal variables instead of x,y,z,a,b,c etc as it helps making it much easier to debug situations like this. Descriptive variables should always be used. For loopRow = 11 To xLastRow
For nextCellValue = 12 To xxLastrow... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This i smoe of a comment than an answer, but as code looks ugly in a comment I thought I would post as answer.

You can accomplish your same results with a much more efficient code, the below code uses value = value instead of copy paste, as to avoid using the clipboard (that itself is a buggy slow process). It also does not loop every single column reducing your loops by (Row matches * Column Count) number of times, probably a lot.

```
Dim rngTest As Range
Dim rngCur As Range
Dim rngCOff As Range

Set rngTest = Range("B11:B" & xLastRow)

For Each rngCur In rngTest
    Set rngCOff = rngCur.Offset(1)
    If rngCur.Value = rngCOff.Value Then
       rngCOff.Offset(, 2).Resize(, xLastColumn - 4).Value = rngCur.Offset(, 2).Resize(, xLastColumn - 4).Value
    End If
Next rngCur
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If we don't set area for range, it  becomes a cell by default? Or why haven't you  mentioned rngCur?

Comment: @Seya I do not understand your comment. rngCur, is a Range, and it is used inside of the loop. `For Each rngCur` and `If rngCur.Value` and one last time on the right hand side of the equal sign inside the if. rngCur, is the Current Range/Cell when looping all of the cells inside of Test Range.